# UIImage resize with hard edges

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage, resize

I need a method for resizing UIImage like in photoshop with "nearest neighbour" resampling. I was looking for some, but everything I found was about CoreGraphics thicks to improve bicubic resampling quality. I have pixel-style design in my app, and a lot of stuff I create by pixel and then enlarge it with x5 multiplier (and it takes a lot of time, so I even close to writing a script for Photoshop). For example:

[image] > [image]

But I really don't need this like result of resampling:

[image]

Maybe anyone will show me the right way.

Comment: As addition I can say that I've found a good way for batch image processing with photoshop "actions". But I still need an answer in order to decrease size of stored resource images.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you draw your image into a graphics context, you can set the graphics context's interpolation quality to "none", like this (e.g. in a view's `drawRect` method):

```
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(c, kCGInterpolationNone);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pixels.png"];
[image drawInRect:self.bounds];
```

If you need the result as a `UIImage` (e.g. to assign it to a built-in UI control), you could do this with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` (you'll find lots of examples for that).

An alternative would be to set the `magnificationFilter` property of an image view's layer:

```
pixelatedImageView.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest;
```

This is probably faster and more memory-efficient, because you don't need to redraw the image.

Comment: This answer looks good, I need to check it in XCode soon to accept. Thanks.